# Trouble with the hint: $g\circ \alpha \circ f'=0$ for an exercise on the $3\times3$ lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

The following is taken from *Module Theory An Approach to Linear Algebra* by T. S. Blyth:

$\style{font-family:inherit;}{\color{Green}{\textbf{Background:}}}$

**Exercise 3.10: [The 3x3 lemma]**  Consider the following diagram of $R$-modules and $R$-morphisms
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> A' @>{\smash{\alpha'}}>> A @>{\smash{\beta'}}>> A'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV{f'}V @VV{f}V @VV{f''}V \\
0 @>>> B' @>{\smash{\alpha}}>> B @>{\smash{\beta}}>> B'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV{g'}V @VV{g}V @VV{g''}V \\
0 @>>> C' @. C @. C'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0\end{CD}

Given that this diagram is commutative, that all three columns are exact and that the top two rows are exact, prove that there exist unique $R$-morphisms $\alpha'': C'\to C$ and  $\beta'': C\to C''$ such that the resulting bottom row is exact and the complete diagram is commutative.

[*Hint.* Observe that $g\circ \alpha \circ f' = 0$ so that $\operatorname{ker}g' = \operatorname{im}f' \subset \operatorname{ker}g \circ \alpha$. Use Theorem 3.4 to produce $\alpha''$. Argue similarly to produce $\beta''$.  Now chase!]

$\style{font-family:inherit;}{\color{Red}{\textbf{Questions:}}}$

I would like to know for the hint in the above exercise, how does one justify $g\circ \alpha \circ f' = 0$? I mean should it not be $g\circ f \circ \alpha' = 0$ instead?  I mean $g\circ f = 0$, due to exactness at $B$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post to use the `CD` (commutative diagram) environment, which is available in MathJax by the command `\require{AMScd}` (like `\usepackage{amscd}` in LaTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use commutativity of the squares in the diagram together with the exactness of the vertical sequences (and of course associativity of composition of arrows in any category):
$$
g \circ \alpha \circ f' = g \circ f \circ \alpha' = 0 \circ \alpha' = 0.
$$

Comment: ah ok ok, that makes more sense now.  Also, thank you with the help with editing my post.  I keep getting confusing advice on what mathjax/latex syntax to use to make my post more reader friendly.

Comment: Btw please rollback my edit, i was just checking if text colour can be added to title

Comment: Okay, I did. :-)

Comment: And maybe edit the title again ("Trouble the hint") :p

Comment: @Saby123 also thank you for your help with the edit.  I keep getting different advice and admonoishments about what latex/mathjax syntax not to use.  Some of them seem to contradict each other.  I am learning how to use winedit and apparently many of the package for winedit can't be used on here and hence a lot of the syntax commands won't work on stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, not all LaTeX functionality works in MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a decent tutorial of the basics that *do* work on this site.